# Does $A'\cap B' = (A \cap B)'$ where $X'$ denotes limit points of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Does $A'\cap B' = (A \cap B)'$, where X' denotes limit points of $X$?   Prove or give counter-example.

I.e. If $x$ is not an element of $A'\cap B'$ then $x$ is not an element of either $A'$ or of $B'$. This means that either $A\cap V$ or $B\cap W$ is a subset of $x$ ($V$, $W$ being open sets). So this means $(A\cap V)\cap(B\cap W)$ subset of $x$. This means $(A\cap B)\cap(V\cap W)$ is a subset of $x$. This means that $x$ is not an element of $(A\cap B)'$ since $V\cap W$ is an open set. Is this correct in showing that one set is a subset of the other?

Comment: Try finding a counterexample in $[0,1]$ with $A$ and $B$ disjoint.

Comment: A = (0,1/2), B = (1/2,1).  So intersection of A' and B' is 1/2 but (A intersection B)' is null set?

Comment: Yes, that's a possible example. What are the limit points of the rationals and the irrationals in the reals?

Comment: Null set vs R??

Comment: Also it seems that one is a subset of the other.  I think I proved it by contrapositive ... is that the case?

Comment: I.e. If x is not an element of A'∩B' then x is not an element of either A' or of B'.  This means that either A∩V or B∩W is a subset of x (V, W being open sets). So this means  (A∩V)∩(B∩W) subset of x.  This means (A∩B)∩(V∩W) is a subset of x.  This means that x is not an element of (A∩B)' since V∩W is an open set.  Is this correct?

Comment: no, the two sets are equivalent if and only if $(1)$ $x\in (A'\cap B')\rightarrow x\in (A \cap B)'$ and $(2)$ $x \in (A\cap B)' \rightarrow x \in A'\cap B'$.  If this equivalence fails for any sets A, B, and you suspect the equivalence is not true, then you need to find a counterexample to show that the statement is **not always** true.

Comment: No I'm not suggesting the 2 sets are equivalent.  I'm suggesting that one is a subset of the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the space $\mathbb R$ let $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb R$ \ $A.$ Then $A'=B'=\mathbb R.$ But $A\cap B,$ and hence $(A\cap B)',$ are both empty.

In general a point $p$ may be a limit point of two disjoint sets $A,B,$ so $p\in A'\cap B'$ but $(A\cap B)'$ will be empty.

A simpler example, in $\mathbb R,$ would be intervals $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2),$ with $p=1.$

Comment: Thanks.  But going the other way is one a subset of the other?  Is my proof above showing this correct?

Comment: You should not say "subset of $x$". What you should say is that if $x\not \in A'\cap B'$ then there are open sets $V,$ and $W$, each containing $x$, with $A\cap V=B\cap W=\phi.$ So $V\cap W$ is an open set containing $x$ and disjoint from $A\cap B$ (why?). so $x\not \in (A\cap B)'.$

Comment: Thanks. Since W disjoint from B clearly W∩V is disjoint from B (and W∩V clearly contains x since V and W each do....and open since intersection of open sets.  A disjoint from W∩V for same reason.   And since A∩B is subset of A, it's disjoint  from V∩W as well ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.